# jQuery handling input form without the <form> element

Tags: jquery

I have this element:

```
<input type="text" id="unique_id" />
```

and I want to get the input string whenever there is some text in the form and the user presses enter.

Is that possible? How do I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: If there's no `<form>` ***there is no `<form>`***. Also, based on what events? `keypress()`?

Comment: For some reason if I wrap the input into the <form> element, it places things on a new line which I don't want.  Is there a way to have the <form> and keep it on the same line?

Comment: Yes, `<form style="display: inline;">`

Comment: Does the other text (or whatever) that you're trying to keep the `form` in-line with have relevance to the form itself? Should that content *also* be *in* the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the element the same way as any other, just use an `id` selector:

```
$('#unique_id').keypress(
    function(e){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

The above will log, to the JavaScript console, the current value of the `input` element on every keypress. If you only need to know what the value is when data entry is complete, then use either `blur()`, or `change()`:

```
$('#unique_id').blur(
    function(e){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });



$('#unique_id').change(
    function(e){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

Note: you don't need to use *both*, I'm just showing them both so you can see how to use them.

References:

- [`blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/).

Comment: That's ok, i thought he wanted to access the value of the input field whenever the user pressed the return key

Answer (score 3):

You could do (i'm doing some mind reading here)

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e){
    if(e.which === 13){
        alert($('#unique_id').val());
    }
});
```

In this way whenever the user presses the return key you cann access the input value

fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/pwrbv/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/notromda/PXgfP/

```
$('#unique_id').change(function() {
    alert($('#unique_id').val());
});
```